# openconnect works but timeouting

Tags: networking, dns, openconnect

All of a sudden my interfaces (eno1, tun1) stop getting ingress traffic so my connections timeouting. It used to work, but some day it stopped.

I thought it was related to DNS names resolving but it's not. When I sniff my traffic the egress traffic is correct but responses come only for DNS and from 8443 and 80 ports (I need also 443). I check my credentials using another machine with Cisco AnyConnect Client with PKCS#11 I use to authn and it's OK. At first glace, it looks like a problem on remote side but I'm not so sure. I've checked my itpables, eBPF programs (XDP, TC), and my router settings. It's fine.

Any ideas?

distro ver: ubuntu 22.10

Comment: I contacted VPN maintainers in my org. It seems to that they drop the traffic cause on basis of a new policy my NIC MAC address is not in the whitelist. I'm checking out...

Comment: Yep, my colleagues drop all traffic for non registered NIC.